# Can't seem to install the correct version of PHP, using apt-get install

Tags: php, apt, php-fpm

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 LTS server, it's a new install on a VPS box from MediaTemple (their ve server). I'm trying to install PHP 5.4.3 on this box, but I'm having a common problem not matter what version I get. I'm trying to get the php-cgi process, so I do the command `apt-get install php-cgi` and that installs, but does not provide me with the `php-cgi` executable. I need this so that I can run `php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000` and have it has a FastCGI process for my nginx install. Any idea what I can do to get this to work, bonus points if you can get this to work with PHP 5.4.3, because all I can seem to install is PHP 5.3.5.

Comment: How about pasting the output from your apt-get (including a `-V` on the command)?  Also, the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  Lastly, once installed, the output of, `dpkg -L php-cgi`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the version of PHP5 CGI in Ubuntu 11.04 LTS is,

> php5-cgi (5.3.5-1ubuntu7.8) [security]

according to [this page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/php/php5-cgi).  You can check which versions are present in other Ubuntu releases on that page.  If you want 5.4.3 you'll either need to find another repository with it in, or download and compile your own version.

It appears you were installing the `php5-cli` package which does not contain the relevant php5-cgi binaries.

Comment: Also, the name of the executable in the Ubuntu package is `php5-cgi` not `php-cgi`

Comment: @DerfK
`user@ts:~# apt-get install php5-cli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5-cli is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
user@ts:~# php -v
PHP 5.4.3-4~natty+1 (cli) (built: May 17 2012 12:52:08) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
user@ts:~# php5-cli -v
-bash: php5-cli: command not found
user@ts:~#`

Comment: @Derfk
`user@ve:~# php -v
PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.8 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: May  4 2012 00:50:15) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
user@ve:~# php5-cli -v
-bash: php5-cli: command not found
user@ve:~# php-cli -v 
-bash: php-cli: command not found
user@ve:~#`

Comment: @MarkTomlin php-cli does *NOT* have the CGI interface and can't be used for your fastcgi service.  You need the program `php5-cgi` in the package `php5-cgi` which you have already installed, it's just an older version.

Comment: I had to install the php5-cgi, but once I did, everything ways working. Sorry for being so dense. +1